# Date Format for String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string of the form "2013-05-12T15:38:20+00:00" but I can't work out why my date formatter won't convert it to an NSDate object. I have tried using "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+zz:zz" and a bunch of variations on it but no luck.

What would be the correct date format for this string?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/15571801/767730

Comment: @Anupdas I got the correct answer from that question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this format

```
NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"];
NSLog(@"notDate =====> %@",[form dateFromString:@"2013-05-12T15:38:20+00:00"]);

NSDate *notDate = [form dateFromString:[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"2013-05-12T15:38:20+00:00"]];
NSLog(@"notDate =====> %@",[form dateFromString:@"2013-05-12T15:38:20+00:00"]);
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Why are you including milliseconds in dateFormat?

Comment: Hi , i have implemented it and it's working at my end , Please have a look on my updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct date format for this string is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"

Thanks @Anupdas for pointing me to a similar question.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, 'z' only works as a *fallback* because it didn't get the expected abbreviation (PDT, CST, etc).  If you want to specify only the format you received, you should use 'ZZZZZ' (ISO8601 format)

Comment: @dattu If it is not working, then you are doing it wrong.  This answer is correct (I verified it myself)

Comment: @borrden From the dateFormat unicode paterns specified for [4.3](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-17.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and [5.1](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns). 5 Z's(+00:00) where introduced from iOS 5.1 onwards. Then why does it work when only 'z' is given.

Comment: @Anupdas It works with "z" for the reason I described in my comment above (failing the actual expected value, it falls back to this format)

Comment: Good point about the versions though.  I didn't realize ZZZZZ was so new ^^

Comment: @borrrden Is it safe to guess that only a character of 'z' or 'Z' is required, as dateFormatter has failover mechanism.

Comment: I didn't disagree @Anupdas ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 
your string

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+zz:zz"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Conversion of the NSString to a NSDate
Now here you change any format as you want

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dddd - MMMM dd,yyy"];
NSString* myNiceLookingDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: This dateFormat won't work

Comment: Take a look at the class reference for NSDateFormatter.http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Kapil Why?  The issue is the format string (something that you seem to not be paying attention to)

Comment: Your dateFormat has no seperators(colons and hyphens) and thus it will not.